# Django : Send a mail to user when entry is created

Tags: python, django, email

I have read some questions about that, but none works with my case.
I want to send a mail to the User when he saves a new entry.

**post/models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.core.mail import EmailMultiAlternatives
from django.template.loader import render_to_string
from django.dispatch import receiver

class Post(models.Model):
    client = models.ForeignKey(User)
    date = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, editable=False)


@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def first_mail(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    if kwargs['created']:
        user_email = instance.User.email
        subject, from_email, to = 'New Post', 'from@example.com', user_email

        text_content = render_to_string('post/mail_post.txt')
        html_content = render_to_string('post/mail_post.html')

        # create the email, and attach the HTML version as well.
        msg = EmailMultiAlternatives(subject, text_content, from_email, [to])
        msg.attach_alternative(html_content, "text/html")
        msg.send()
```

This signal does not send any email. I am using mail_panel to track the email.

Comment: `instance.User.email` is it correct??

Comment: btw signals sender should be not on User, but Post... the changed, saved object is of class Post, sot after saving it the signal will be emitted

Comment: let know if it worked for you and accept answer if so ;)

Comment: Thanks andi, it works :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refering to django documentation:

> sender - The model class.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/signals/#post-save

So if you are saving object of class Post, then the signals sender is Post and not the User.

Then in signal you refer to `instance` (which is object of class `Post`), and access its field `client` (FK linked, instance of class `User`) and get its field `email`.

proper form:

```
user_email = instance.client.email
```

assuming there in class User is present field with email.